# hyperref targets without \refstepcounter

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am trying to create a document-internal link using the `hyperref` package.  At the position where the link should point to, I execute the following command (as part of the setup of a LaTeX environment):

```
\edef\@currentlabel{LABEL}
```

After this, I use `\label{...}` to create a reference and the `\ref{...}`.  The `hyperref` package turns the `\ref{...}` into a hyperlink as expected, but the link points to the wrong location (further up in the text).  How do I tell `hyperref` where the link should point to?

I cannot use `\refstepcounter` because my labels are textual and not associated to a LaTeX counter.

Here is a "minimal" (well, "smallish") working example to illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{algorithm}[2]%
  {\medbreak
   \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
   % more stuff here (put entry in table of algorithms, etc.)
   \noindent
   \textbf{Algorithm~\@currentlabel\ (#2)}\hfill\break
   \ignorespaces}%
  {\medbreak}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{algorithm}{TEST}{Test Algorithm}\label{alg:TEST}%
  \lipsum[2]
\end{algorithm}

The following link points to the theorem instead of the algorithm: \ref{alg:TEST}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noindent\phantomsection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an anchor in the appropriate spot. This is done automatically when `\refstepcounter` is issued, but you have to do it manually when `\@currentlabel` is set without the help of a counter.

An anchor can be set with `\phantomsection` (it's a bad name, though).

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{algorithm}[2]%
  {\medbreak
   \edef\@currentlabel{#1}%
   % more stuff here (put entry in table of algorithms, etc.)
   \noindent\phantomsection % <------------------------ add the anchor
   \textbf{Algorithm~\@currentlabel\ (#2)}\hfill\break
   \ignorespaces}%
  {\medbreak}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the package's `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` macros. They don't require any counters, `\refstepcounter` actions, or redefinitions of `\@currentlabel`.

- Insert `\hypertarget{<anchor name>}{<some text>}` in the location *to which* the reader should jump.
- Insert `\hyperlink{<anchor name>}{<other text>}` in one or more locations *from which* the reader should jump, to the location specified elsewhere in the document by a `\hypertarget` instruction.

A very simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\hypertarget{jump_destination}{\textbf{A wonderful tale}}

Once upon a time, \dots

\clearpage

If you want to read a wonderful tale, click \hyperlink{jump_destination}{here}.

\end{document}
```

The word "here" on the second page will be shown in blue, and clicking on it will take you to the line "A wonderful tale" on the preceding page.

It's possible to have multiple `\hyperlink` instructions pointing to the same anchor name, but there should be only one `\hypertarget` instruction for a given anchor name.

Adapting these ideas to your test code, it might look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,amsthm,hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newenvironment{algorithm}[2]%
  {\par\medbreak\noindent
    % more stuff here (put entry in table of algorithms, etc.)
    \hypertarget{#1}{\textbf{Algorithm~#1 (#2)}}%
    \par\noindent\ignorespaces}%
  {\medbreak}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{algorithm}{TEST}{Test Algorithm}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{algorithm}

\clearpage
The following link now points to the algorithm: \hyperlink{TEST}{here}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make `\ref{...}` link to the correct spot using this approach?

Comment: @jochen - `\ref` works in conjunction with `\label` which, in turn, typically requires some action that increments a counter and updates `\@currentlabel` in the process. (As egreg mentions in his answer, modifying `\@currentlabel` by hand isn't enough in your case -- one also needs to issue the instruction `\phantomsection`.) Given that you want an approach that doesn't involve any counter variables incremented by `\refstepcounter`, I think it's a good idea to rely on the `\hyperlink`/`\hypertarget` mechanism, which is provided by the `hyperref` package for just such a case.